# How to copy char array to char pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have two variables as stated below. How do I copy the contents of "varOrig" to "varDest" (no loops `for` ou `while`)?

```
const char* varDest = "";
char varOrig[34]     = "12345";
```

Comment: Are you asking how to assign the base address of `varOrig` to the pointer variable `varDest` ?

Comment: You can copy to a *memory* pointed by a pointer, but not to a pointer. In this case the memory pointed is both read only and too small.

Comment: you need to allocate memory to `varDest` rather than pointing it to `""`, then you can `strcpy`.

Comment: `varDest = strdup(varOrig);` don't forget to free memory after use, because `strdup` use `malloc` inside

Comment: I've solved like this: `varDest = &varOrig[0]` or `varDest = strdup(varOrig)` as @NickS said.

Comment: Your question, method 1 and method 2 are 3 totally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to copy the address of the array to the pointer, do this:

```
varDest = varOrig;
```

---

Otherwise, you will need to allocate memory and copy the string.

`strdup` is useful for this:

```
varDest = strdup(varOrig);
```

You need to free `varDest` after using this.

Answer (score 2):

`memcpy` is the fastest library routine for memory-to-memory copy. It is usually more efficient than `strcpy`, which must scan the data it copies or `memmove`, which must take precautions to handle overlapping inputs.

```
// Defined in header <string.h>
void* memcpy( void *dest, const void *src, size_t count );
```

This code.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
...
char varOrig[34] = "12345";
// calculate length of the original string
int length = strlen(varOrig);
// allocate heap memory, length + 1 includes null terminate character
char* varDest = (char*)malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
// memcpy, perform copy, length + 1 includes null terminate character
memcpy(varDest, varOrig, length+1);
```

Comment: Citation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy